# Error creating bean with name '_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap

Tags: java, maven, mule

I am trying to compile a maven project, in this project I am trying to create a custom connector with of mule. But when I am trying to package this project using the following command `mvn -X clean package -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false` I getting the following error  `Error creating bean with name '_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap'`

I am providing the link to my pom.xml file and error file that have full stack trace.
[pom.xml file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zpiw92a8jwrfpd/pom.xml)

[error file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9pqag28l7xx3hi/org.hello.Odata3ConnectorTest.txt)

Thanks.

Comment: The links do not work.

Comment: use http://pastebin.com/ for the output

Comment: @Jens I have checked the above links, they are working fine. What is the response you are getting back.

Comment: @Vijay Sorry looks like a proxy problem.

Comment: @AVolpe for pom.xml file - http://pastebin.com/q0W9dGW1  and for error file:- http://pastebin.com/KbBhRtC0

Comment: From the conversation on this link I found out tgat

Comment: From the conversation on the below link it seems that this problem can be solved by adding some dependency, but which?  https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/mule-user/nkjU9dzvtXE

Comment: Have you seen [this link](http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/Mule-embedded-in-weblogic-9-2-webapp-Error-creating-bean-with-name-muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap-definl-td2654879.html) maybe it helps?

Comment: @Jens This link says that there might be issue of duplicate jar file, but this is not the case. Also I came to know that this issue is coming when I am trying to add the following depedency, 

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.msopentech.odatajclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>odatajclient-engine</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>

Does anybody have ay idea about that.